# How to solve $\frac{1}{2\sin50^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to solve the expression $\frac{1}{2\sin50^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ$ to get a much simpler and neater result. I have tried to manipulate this expression such as using sum/difference formulas, but it didn't help (and made the expression even more messy).

Here is what I did:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\sin50^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ&=\frac{1}{2\sin(60-10)^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ \\
&= \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\cos10^\circ-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin10^\circ\right)}+2\sin10^\circ \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos10^\circ-\sin10^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos10^\circ+\sin10^\circ}{\left(\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos10^\circ-\sin10^\circ\right)\left(\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos10^\circ+\sin10^\circ\right)}+2\sin10^\circ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot\cos10^\circ+\sin10^\circ}{3\cos^210^\circ-\sin^210^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ
\end{align}
But I don't know how to continue at this point. Multiplying in $2\sin10^\circ$ into the fraction is clearly unrealistic as it would result in trignometry of third power. Any help or hint would be appreciated. According to a calculator, the result of this expression should come to a nicely $1$, but I just want to know how to algebraically manipulate this expression to *show* that it is equal to $1$.

Comment: You can, maybe, use the fact that $\cos^2 10^\circ - \sin^2 10^\circ = \cos 20^\circ$ in the denominator but I don't think that will help.

Comment: We do not solve an expression (an equation, yes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac1{2\sin50^\circ}+2\sin10^\circ&=\frac{1+4\sin50^\circ\sin10^\circ}{2\sin50^\circ}\\
&=\frac{1+2(\cos40^\circ-\cos60^\circ)}{2\cos40^\circ}\\&=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: How does the second step work? ($2\sin50^\circ\sin10^∘=\cos40^∘−\cos60^∘$)

Answer (score 4):

Always remember : "never simplify denominator unless you know the values."

Onto the answer :

just cross multiply to get $$\frac{1 + 4 \sin50 \sin10}{2 \sin50}$$

which would further simplify as $$\frac{1+2(\cos40 - \cos60)}{2\sin50}$$

which is easy to solve as we get $$\frac{\cos40}{\sin50} = 1$$

so the answer is 1

Comment: Formatting tip: your posts will look better and be easier to read if you use `\sin`, `\cos` and so on.

Comment: @saulspatz why arent my expressions big enough ?

Comment: @omjoglekar I have edited the post is it fine now?

Comment: yes, thamks a lot

Comment: How does the second expression work? ($2\sin50^\circ\sin10^\circ=\cos40^\circ-\cos60^\circ$)

Comment: basic transformation formulae. find a list of the 4 formulae here : https://img.brainkart.com/extra2/4aSw5cF.jpg
These will probably be taught to you soon if you don't know them

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}} + 2 \sin{10^{\circ}}= \frac{1}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}} + 2 \sin{(60^{\circ}-50^{\circ})}=\frac{1}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}} + \sqrt{3} \cos{50^{\circ}} -\sin{50^{\circ}} =$$
$$=\frac{1-2 \sin^2{50^{\circ}}}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}}+\frac{2\sqrt{3} \cos{50^{\circ}}\sin{50^{\circ}}}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}}=\frac{\cos{100^{\circ}}}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\sin{100^{\circ}}}{2\sin{50^{\circ}}} =$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cos{100^{\circ}} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin{100^{\circ}}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}} = \frac{\sin{(30^{\circ}+100^{\circ})}}{\sin{50^{\circ}}}=1$$